# Problem with Certificate when connecting to Eventstore using EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, grpc, eventstoredb

Good afternoon.

I am trying to connect to an Eventstore single node instance (self deployed on azure vm without docker) from various web services written in asp.net core. When running the services with docker and docker-compose, there is a certification issue. When running the service without docker, there is not.

My question is, what is the requirements regarding to the certificate of the web application to connect to Eventstore using grpc successfully?

The error i got is the following

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

Is this exception caused by an self signed certificate?

Comment: How did you generate your certificates?

Comment: The current dev environment i am using use a asp.net core development certificate, which is as i know a trusted self signed certificate, delivered by the asp.net core framework.

Comment: Ok, if you want to have similar experience, we have introduced a "dev mode" for local environments. You can check the release notes https://www.eventstore.com/blog/22.10.0-release-notes, basically you need to start it with `--dev` option. However, I know that it doesn't work in Docker without doing some permissions work, need to check internally.

Comment: The development environment is only for developing purpose. In the production environment we are using an azure kubernetes cluster with let's encryped certificate for nginx in place. But I guess the asp.net core webapplication will not use these certificate for grpc. Can you inform me about the certificate requirements?

Comment: The exception you posted implies that it's not about EventStoreDB at all. The gRPC connection fails on the client, and behind it shows an exception from HttpClient. I bet if you just make an HTTP call to that ESDB instance, it will fail with the same exception. I still don't fully understand your setup. It might be useful to continue the discussion on our Discord server https://discuss.eventstore.com/t/join-our-new-discord/4911